# VBA checkboxes in Word

Tags: vba, checkbox, activex, ms-word

I have a word document which has lots of pages, and sections which after each step have an `ActiveX` control check box.

At the end of the document there is a completion table which has the name of the sections and when the last check box for a certain section is checked, it turns that part of the table green.

So for an example:

SECTION 1:

Text

(Checkbox 1)

moretext

(Checkbox 2)

evenmoretext

(Checkbox 3)

Completion list:

Section 1

What I am trying to achieve is have some vba that will check to see if ALL of the checkboxes are ticked, and then make the section one part on the table at the end green.

I currently have it working so it turns it green but only when then last checkbox (3) is checked.

Is there anyway to do this?

There is also another matter: I have a button at the top of the document that hides a few of the sections throughout the document, which when pressed, checks any checkboxes it is going to be hiding first. (I use page breaks to show which parts I want to hide)

This is a problem however because the `ActiveX` checkboxes do not hide, and so I have written some VBA which instead makes them super tiny, and then resizes them after its done.

Here is the vba I have so far:

```
Private Sub DTSCheckBox_Click()

    If (DTSCheckBox.Value = True And AdminCheckBox.Value = True) Then
        Section2Complete.Caption = "Complete"
        Section2Complete.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        CheckAndAmmendBy.Caption = UpgradeTechnic.Text
    Else
        Section2Complete.Caption = "Outstanding"
        Section2Complete.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        CheckAndAmmendBy.Caption = ""
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub V4ToV6Button_Click()

    ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Range.Font.Hidden = True
    ActiveDocument.Sections(4).Range.Font.Hidden = True
    ActiveDocument.Sections(6).Range.Font.Hidden = True
    ActiveDocument.Sections(8).Range.Font.Hidden = True
    Section15Complete.Caption = "": Section15Complete.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(15).SetHeight 1, wdRowHeightExactly
    SQLScriptCheckbox.Value = True
    SQLScriptCheckbox.Height = 1
    SQLScriptCheckbox.Width = 1
    SQLScriptCheckbox.Enabled = False
    RestoreEmailScriptCheckBox.Value = True
    RestoreEmailScriptCheckBox.Height = 1
    RestoreEmailScriptCheckBox.Width = 1
    RestoreEmailScriptCheckBox.Enabled = False
    SQLCleanScriptCheckBox.Value = True
    SQLCleanScriptCheckBox.Height = 1
    SQLCleanScriptCheckBox.Width = 1
    SQLCleanScriptCheckBox.Enabled = False
    SandboxJobHasBeenSetUpCheckBox.Value = True
    SandboxJobHasBeenSetUpCheckBox.Width = 1
    SandboxJobHasBeenSetUpCheckBox.Height = 1
    SandboxJobHasBeenSetUpCheckBox.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your design is, but assuming you have 3 checkboxes and you want to hide the section if all three are checked or show the section otherwise (including re-showing the section if the user unchecks one of the three), I suggest creating a separate function that updates the format of the section anytime a checkbox is clicked:

```
Private Sub CheckBox21_Click()
    UpdateSection
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox22_Click()
    UpdateSection
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox23_Click()
    UpdateSection
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateSection()
    If CheckBox21.Value = True And CheckBox22.Value = True And CheckBox23.Value = True Then
        'Code to hide section
    Else
        'Code to show section
    End If
End Sub
```